# How does a YouTube embedded video incorporate the player design?

Tags: html, video

I have designed custom video player controls for my HTML5 video. I was wondering how I can have that design incorporated to videos that are also embedded. I took a look at youtube to see how they would do it :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/V1Q1FFTga8k" frameborder="0"         
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This looks like a piece of a cake , but this doesn't show me how the player design was incorporated.

Can someone please explain to me how I can have my video design show on embedded videos.

Note: I am assuming that in order to make an embedded feature for my videos; I would just need the iframe with the set attributes and dynamically putting the url for whichever video is currently playing.

Comment: For one, you can't change the contents of the iframe, unless your page is also running under www.youtube.com. You're probably looking for the [youtube api documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#chromeless_player) on how to get started with the chromeless player.

Comment: How does YouTube achieve this feature? I am trying to make my own videos , hosted on my site, with the same feature as youtube. I want my custom player to show on videos when its embedded. I already know how to make a custom html5 video player , I just dont know how to incorporate the design to a video that will be embedded. Help me someone!